# Cut corners in pure CSS

Tags: css, shapes

Does anyone have any technique to accomplish cut corners:

[image]

using CSS only? (they use images)

I thought about placing four absolutely positioned CSS triangles, with the background color, on top of a box, but you can really only put two CSS triangles (:before, :after) without wrapping it in two wrappers, and it would be chaotic to start adding borders.

I think the answer is a negative but you never know :)

EDIT:

Just to clarify I'm talking about "cut" corners as in the image above, not rounded corners as achieved with border-radius.

Comment: Are you taking about rounded corners ? or angles?

Comment: The image above uses border-radius, most likely, even though that isn't what you're asking for.

Comment: If you actually want to use angles as corners, there are several ways to do this with just css, if you are still interested in knowing how, please let me know, I will help you

Comment: ofcourse he's interested, enlighten us.

Comment: After looking at Halliburton's website, the bottom part of that element is a separate element.

Comment: I blame this issue on designers who just want the cut corners and not ok with rounded corners

Comment: @Huangism Don't blame to mockup-designer, coz, web-designer can make such design using image easily... But OP was interested to make it with css only, that's it. Nothing else is important in the view of designer....

Comment: Using the border way, it work only if you are not using a dropshadow or different background colors for your page or even a background pattern. if you do, this option its useless. I will create fiddle with my own solution

Comment: @C-linkNepal that's why they are to blame because they don't think about development.

Comment: OH! you meant to be that, but we really can't blame them coz we, as being a web designer, have to work as what they need...

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is my solution. Im sure I could simplify the css a lot more, but the general idea is here.

Here is my fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/uaf7sdor/1/

As you can see in my example, u can set any background image or color to body and this wont interfere with the corners

Here is my **HTML**

```
<div class="randomBG">


<div class="myBox">
    <div class="corner" loc="tl">
        <div class="tl"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="corner" loc="tr">
        <div class="tr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="corner" loc="bl">
        <div class="bl"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="corner" loc="br">
        <div class="br"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="myBoxContent">
        <div class="inner">
            Hello world  dwq dwq dwqwdjb oidbwqoid bwqoi<br />
            bouiwq bdiw<br />
            <br />
            <br />
            YO
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is my **CSS**

```
.randomBG {
    background: url(http://gdj.gdj.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/background-pattern-design-11.jpg);
    padding: 50px;
}
.corner {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.corner div[class] {
    background-color: #AAA;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
     border: #444 solid 1px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE9 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; 

}
.corner .tl {
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
}
.corner .tr {
    top: 10px;
    left: -25px;
}
.corner .bl {
    top: -35px;
    left: 0px;
}
.corner .br {
    top: -35px;
    left: -25px;
}

.myBox {
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.myBox .myBoxContent {
    background-color: #AAA;
    display: inline-block;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
.myBox [loc="tl"] {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.myBox [loc="tr"] {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.myBox [loc="bl"] {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.myBox [loc="br"] {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.myBox .myBoxContent::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: #444 solid 1px;
}
.myBox .myBoxContent::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
}
.myBox .myBoxContent .inner::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -25px;
    border-left: #444 solid 1px;
}
.myBox .myBoxContent .inner::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -25px;
    border-right: #444 solid 1px;
}
```